# select list in edit form

Tags: php, html, mysql, list, select

I have this code to collect categories from the field "category" from Mysql, it is a part editing form, i want the category that was selected before to be selected after the list is filled, the code is :

```
 <td align="right">Category</td>
     <td>
         <?php
        // Write out our query.
        $query = "SELECT id,cat_name,parent FROM categories WHERE parent='0'";
        // Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $dropdown = "<select name='category'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['cat_name']}</option>";
        }
        $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
        echo $dropdown;
        ?>
        </td>
```

I don't know how to do it? i know that i should type "selected" on the option i want to select but how to choose it after i filled the list?

Comment: Where do you save the previous choice?  The server has no idea what you've chosen previously if you don't persist it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an indexed tab `$tab["key"]` this way you can easily find the line that you want and edit it.

Edit: Your message isn't very clear, but I figured that's want you want to do. Otherwise, clarify please.

Comment: i use variables to retrieve from the database using the id of the product, i have a variable called "Category" which has the name of the category i want to select in the list, but how to select it after it was filled , thats my question

Comment: Like I said, use and indexed tab: $dropdown["categoryname"] this way you can find the good line easily after filling the tab. Or check directly in the loop, like Liam suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're not checking what the user has selected previously. You can do that with something like this:

```
$selected = '';
if($row['id']==$userSelectedOption) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
$dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['id']}'{$selected}>{$row['cat_name']}</option>";
```

In the above example, we have a variable named `$userSelectedOption` which represents the value a user has already selected. We're also assuming that it is the ID of a category. Within your `while` loop you would use the above 3 line instead of your one line. When this renders out the list will have the selected item be whatever matches `$userSelectedOption`